# Spring Bind Exception

Tags: spring-mvc

i got exception in my controller class using bindexception.using reject method how i can print the message in my jsp.

Comment: Can you post some piece of code ???

Answer (score 0):

maybe I dont understant correct, but when you wont to check exception in SpringMVC, you can use
Class **SimpleleMappingExceptionResolver** or you can implements **HandlerExceptionResolver**.

See
http://tomasjurman.blogspot.com/2010/01/exception-handling-in-spring-mvc.html